# Can I create adjectives with -type suffix?

Tags: adjectives, compounds

In a document, I define two different types of memory accesses (but it could be anything else):

> We distinguish between two types of memory accesses: *mem1* accesses and *mem2* accesses because they may hit
>   different cache levels.

Can I then refer to theses two types of memory accesses as: *mem1*-type accesses and *mem2*-type accesses ?

For instance:

> In this section, we analyze *mem1*-type accesses, ...
>   On the contrary, *mem2*-type accesses, ...

I wonder if I can do that because *mem1* and *mem2* are not english words, they rather are  abitrary identifiers. I have already seen:

> A flu-type disease
>   Dram-type memory

but never

> 1-type diabetes

Comment: Why do you think you wouldn't be able to?

Comment: Because mem1 and mem2 are not "real" english words. I wondered if I could combine these "arbitrary identifiers" with -type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use -type in the way you are asking. According to the Macmillan Dictionary the suffix ***[-type](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/type_3)*** is:

> - used with many nouns and adjectives to make adjectives meaning having the qualities or features of a particular person, thing, or group.
>
>   - a flu-type illness

- As for diabetes, the common definition is *'[type 1 diabetes](http://www.diabetes.org/diabetes-basics/type-1/) '.*

Answer (score 1):

This is sounding a bit confused.  Here are some valid formulations:

> I have flu-like symptoms.
>
> I have Type 1 diabetes.
>
> We will define two types of memory access: Mem-1 and Mem-2.

And then of course you have to give your definitions, which I suppose will have something to do with hitting different cache levels.

Here's an example of how you would use your terms once you've defined them (I'm just making something up here):

> We will now address some counter-intuitive performance effects that can be observed with Mem-1 access.